MS assembly Top layer
Would you please let me know why do we need MS assembly Top layer in a PCB? What is the application?


That's not "MS", it's "M5" which is probably "mechanical layer 5." Mechanical layers can be whatever you want them to be, from assembly instructions to carbon deposition to stiffeners for flex PCB, etc.
See Working with Mechanical Layers in the official documentation for more information.

Most PCB layout programs allow several extra layers beyond those actually needed to produce the PC board.  These extra layers can be used for whatever the designer wants.
The designer of that board may be using the M5 layer to produce an assembly drawing - information on that layer will be different than, or in addition to, the top silkscreen layer.
